# Separate all multipage PDF files inside a directory into single page PDFs via Python

Tags: python, pdf

I need to take hundreds of randomly named multipage PDF files and split them into single-page PDF files.  I have been experimenting with Python with some success.  The following code does exactly what I need, but it is written to split a 'specific' PDF file (w9.pdf).  I need to split all PDF files in a directory (*.pdf).

Can somebody point me in the right direction, please?

```
# pdf_splitter.py

import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def pdf_splitter(path):
fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]


pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

    output_filename = '{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(
        fname, page+1)


    with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

    print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'w9.pdf'
    pdf_splitter(path)
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you the following solution:

```
import glob

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paths = glob.glob('*.pdf')
    for path in paths:
        pdf_splitter(path)
```

Comment: Yes  That worked!  Needed to add 'import glob' first, but it worked!  Thank you!!!

Comment: Cool. I added the `import glob` in my answer. If OK for you, you can accept it.